# Cumulating Animation with CSS

Tags: html, css, animation, transition, target

I'm trying to make a kind of animated website **only** using **CSS Animations** with the `:target` selector

I made up my first cascade and then the main problem is encountered :

I can't animate anymore. Maybe because I am not sure of every lines of the code I am using, that is why I am coming to you.

> Basically the **effect** is actually **working** on the **2nd link** only.

Here is a small piece of my code:

```css
.saq {
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
  color: yellow;
  margin-left: 815px;
  border: 1px black solid;
  margin-top: -550px;
  transition: 4s ease-in-out;
  position: absolute
}

.qaq {
  width: 60px;
  height: 110px;
  margin-left: 1205px;
  margin-top: -550px;
  transition: 5s ease-in-out;
  position: absolute;
  display: inline;
  cursor: auto;
  background-color: black;
  z-index: 1000
}

a {
  font-size: 100px;
  text-align: right
}

;
.navi {
  margin-left: 400px;
  transform: translate(300px, 200px);
}

nav a {
  background-color: yellow;
  display: inline-block
}

nav a:hover {
  background-color: brown;
  color: yellow;
}

#s1:target {
  display: block;
  transition: all 4s ease;
  transform: translate(300px, 350px) rotate(90deg) scale(0.6);
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden
}

#move #s1:target~.saq {
  transform: translateY(-1720px)
}

#move #s1:target~.qaq {
  transform: translateY(-1720px)
}
```

```html
<div id=move>
  <nav class=navi id=s1>
    <ul><a href="#s2">Home</a></ul>
    <ul><a href="#s1">Creations</a></ul>
    <ul><a href="#s3">About</a></ul>
    <ul><a href="#">Contact</a></ul>

  </nav>


  <div class="qaq"></div>
  <div class="saq"></div>
```

Here is the link of the page : http://faxe-kondi.16mb.com/bru.html

Here what I have done so far, is a lot of div moving after the `#s1` is targeted.

What i am looking to do : Making a lot of div move after the `#s3` is targeted.

Maybe it is a selector problem, or children/sibling, or maybe I cannot use two animation on the same `div`.

But of course there is a solution you can bring to me.

Answer (score 0):

The `:target` selector works alright in your code. But you only use it for the `#s1:target` rule. Which in your HTML is only the second link.

For example:

```css
.links>a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.link1 {
  background: red;
}

.link2 {
  background: blue;
}

.link3 {
  background: green;
}

.animated-box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  transition: border-radius 1s;
}

.animated-box:target {
  border-radius: 0;
}

#box1 {
  background: red;
}

#box2 {
  background: blue;
}

#box3 {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="links">
  <a class="link1" href="#box1"></a>
  <a class="link2" href="#box2"></a>
  <a class="link3" href="#box3"></a>
</div>

<div class="animated-box" id="box1"></div>
<div class="animated-box" id="box2"></div>
<div class="animated-box" id="box3"></div>
```

See, the difference here is how you apply the transition-effect (`border-radius: 0`). If you want to target only one element you can go with a selector like `#s1:target` but it then will only happen in case the element with `id="s1"` gets the target (meaning, the link with `href="#s1"` gets clicked).

You either want to specify more CSS rules like you did with `#s1:target` or you want to use a class instead like I did below.

Comment: Hello and thank you for this answer.
I see clearer but something is disturbing.
the #s1:target i am using is working right. I thought it was referring to the "href=#s1" and not to the "id=s1"

Seems like im making wrong sentences. 
Im tryingout right now your vision

Comment: In CSS it refers to the id. So if you write something like `#s1:target {background: blue;}` it would read as: Select the element with the id `s1` and if it gets the target (if a link with `href="#s1"` gets clicked) make it's background blue.

Comment: So i tried giving id to the links in the nav. It is not working.
 I gave the id's1' to my nav, maybe i shouldnt have to, but unfortunately only one link is working like that :D 

I suppose i should reorganize my html but even though there is something i am missing with the :target full sentence. I used : #move #s1:target ~.square . In order to make respond the square, sibling of target in the move parent. Isnt there something different to 'call' the id.
(such as > for parent...)

Comment: Well, assuming the HTML is as you posted, the `~` won't work either. This is the general sibling selector. And `.square` is no sibling of `#s1` because it is inside `<nav>` and `.square` is not.

Answer (score 0):

can you test it?

```
<div id=move>
    <nav class=navi id=s1>
        <ul><a href="#s1">Home</a></ul>
        <ul><a href="#s1">Creations</a></ul>
        <ul><a href="#s1">About</a></ul>
        <ul><a href="#s1">Contact</a></ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="qaq"></div>
    <div class="saq"></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Hello and thank you for your answer, its true i didnt close the div, mistake from my part in the example it is because there is many other divs into the #move in order to make some sibling connection with the ':target ~'
Maybe there is other way to relate the 'link' to the 'one moving' in some sentences